# converting pure string to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have a string like below

```
 "{stockName: NSE:APOLLOTYRE, stockSignal: Buy, triggerPrice: 204.25, triggerDate: 44900}"
```

Now how can I convert this to json as below:

```
    {
    stockName: APOLLOTYRE, 
    stockSignal: Buy, 
    triggerPrice: 204.25, 
    triggerDate: 44900
}
```

Please note that "NSE:" should be deleted from resulting JSON
I tried below code but obviously it not working.

```
 var data_array = input.body.split(',');
        var json = JSON.stringify(data_array);
        console.log(json);
```

Comment: @abhishekkannojia, JSON.parse() doesnot work!!

Comment: That's because it's not proper JSON. String values should be in quotes.

Comment: It's not properly formatted JSON so it can't be parsed as such. How was the string generated? It should be stringified from an object at some point, not constructed manually, to ensure that it's properly formatted.

Comment: Does the format have specs? I mean, can you get stuff like `stockSignal: Buy,Sell` or entirely different structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *String.replace* to add quotes to the properties in your pseudo-JSON to convert it to proper JSON, then use JSON.parse:

```js
var input = "{stockName: NSE:APOLLOTYRE, stockSignal: Buy, triggerPrice: 204.25, triggerDate: 44900}";

var withQuotes = input.replace(/(\b[a-z]+:)?(\b[a-z]+\b)/gi, '"$2"');

var parsed = JSON.parse(withQuotes);

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: your solution works, but unfortunately, I update the complete question. and I need to delete a string before the final JSON, could you please help here?

Comment: Sure, I updated the regular expression to remove any letters + ':' prepending a string.

Comment: @PatrickHund I know this is an old question/answer I have the same string converting to JSON, the value has percentage symbol (%) like (stockSignal: 10%) I'm not able to convert it.

Comment: Try this modified version of the regular expression: /(\b[a-z]+:)?(\b[a-z]+\b|\b[0-9]+\b%)/gi

Answer (score 1):

For transorm your string into JSON object you have to make this:

`var s = "{stockName: APOLLOTYRE, stockSignal: Buy, triggerPrice: 204.25, triggerDate: 44900}"`

like this:

`var s = "{\"stockName\": \"APOLLOTYRE\", \"stockSignal\": \"Buy\", \"triggerPrice\": 204.25, \"triggerDate\": 44900}"`

and after you can parse it from json to javaScript object with

`JSON.parse(s);`

You can try something like this:

`var s =  "{stockName: APOLLOTYRE, stockSignal: Buy, triggerPrice: 204.25, triggerDate: 44900}";`

`s = s.replace(/{/g, '{\"');`

`s = s.replace(/}/g, '\"}');`

`s = s.replace(":", '\":\"');`

`s = s.replace(/, /g, '\",\"');`

`JSON.parse(s);`