# String to JavaScript JSON/Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have string like array and object want to convert it to pure javascript object or JSON.

My string example:

```
"`{keyOne: valueOne, KeyTow: [10, true, null, 10%], keyThree: {hello: hi}}`"
```

I found a solution converting string to JSON here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907123/4578250

the result with above solution is:

```
{"keyOne": "valueOne", "KeyTow": [10, true, null, "10"%], "keyThree": {"hello": "hi"}}
```

I want the result like:

```
{"keyOne": "valueOne", "KeyTow": [10, true, null, "10%"], "keyThree": {"hello": "hi"}}
```

But I'm not able to convert the string with percentage symbol.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of your original string? If you control it you should consider making it a valid JSON string so that you can simply call `JSON.parse()` on it.

Comment: And what are the replacements you are trying? Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @NickParsons JSON.parse() only work when the string is exact json string... but my string is not exact like json string.

Comment: See [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) as an entrypoint to understand the type of task that you're asking about. JavaScript does not include any native APIs for handling this kind of string parsing scenario. You are going to have to either find a community algorithm or implement one on your own. [Here's a link to the current RFC which specifies the JSON format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259): you'll find it indispensable if you attempt an implementation.

Comment: @ash That's my point - your real issue here seems to be that your original string isn't a valid JSON string, and I'm asking why isn't it? If you control what's producing that string, then you should change that part of your code so it produces a valid JSON string that it's easy to parse (that can be done by creating a regular object and calling `JSON.stringify()` on it)

Comment: @NickParsons you are right, my string is not valid JSON, the string is coming directly from HTML, and I can't force the user make it valid JSON, and that's the first term of agreement :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote all alphanumeric sequences, except for those that are true, false, null, or a number:

```js
let s = "`{keyOne: valueOne, KeyTow: [10, true, null, 10%], keyThree: {hello: hi}}`"

let r = s.replaceAll('`', '').replaceAll(/([\w%]+)/g, m =>
  m.match(/^\d[\d.]*$/) || ['true','false','null'].includes(m) ? m : `"${m}"`)

console.log(JSON.parse(r))
```